# error: not found: value PlayScala - sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

My application Scala was working until a week ago, but I don't know what happened that it isn't anymore. I can't compile the application, every time I try the error bellow is showed

```
name := """xxxx"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    cache,
    ws,
    "com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.3.10",
    "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc"                       % 
    "2.1.4",
    "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-play-plugin"           % "2.3.3",
    "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-play-fixture-plugin"   % "2.3.3"
)
```

`C:\Users\Pedro\Documents\jd_workspace\rsiWS\build.sbt:5: error: not found: value PlayScala
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
                                                     ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression`

Comment: have you added this plugin in the plugins.sbt file?

Comment: Or any `.sbt` file under the `project` folder?